# How to send mail on iMac LAN without Internet connection?

Tags: macos, mac, home-networking

I want to send mails on several iMac connected to a LAN, however I do no have an Internet connection.  I searched several forums but found solutions only for Windows.

Is it possible to send mail on Mac LAN without Internet and if so, how?

Comment: Set up a mail server on one of them?

Comment: please explain the step by step process to do so